# Run jQuery Coffeescript on input change

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have a jQuery Coffeescript function that runs on page load. The functions grabs a table row then it's price, quantity and discounts and processes the values to determine a total for the row.

I currently run the function on page load but would also like it to run anytime that the form input values change. Please Note, this form is used on a rails f.fields_for which generates multiple forms and also additional dynamically generated forms.

What would be the most DRY way to do this?

```
$('tr.order-item').each ->
  q = $(this).find('.quantity_input')
    .val()
  quantity = parseInt(q)
  p = $(this).find('.price').text().replace("$", "")
  price = parseFloat(p.replace(/,/g, ''), 10)
  d = $(this).find('.discount_input').val()
  discount = parseFloat(d)
  total = price * quantity - discount
  total_price = "$"+ parseFloat(total, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString()
  $(this).find('.item-total').text(total_price)
```

form_for fields

```
<tr class="order-item">
<td>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn-u dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li>
            </li>
            <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
            <%= link_to "Remove Item", '#', class: "remove_fields btn btn-link" %>
            <li><button class="btn btn-link">Add Custom Item</button></li>
            <li><button class="btn btn-link">Remove Item</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <h5 class="product"><%= f.object.product.name %></h5>
    <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, class:"product-id" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :id, class:"id" %>
</td>
<td>
    <h5 class="text-right"><span style="color: green" class="price"><%= number_to_currency f.object.unit_price %></span></h5>
</td>
<td>
    <%= f.number_field :quantity, min: 1, hide_label: true, class:"quantity_input" %>
</td>
<td>
    <%= f.text_field :discount, hide_label: true, class:"discount_input" %>
</td>
<td>
    <h5 class="text-right"><span style="color: green" class="item-total"></span></h5>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach would be to listen for the `keyup` event in any input field and then update the values:

```
updateOrderItems = ->
  $(document).find('tr.order-item').each ->
    q = $(this).find('.quantity_input').val()
    quantity = parseInt(q)
    p = $(this).find('.price_value').text()
    price = parseFloat(p)
    d = $(this).find('.discount_input').val()
    discount = parseFloat(d)
    total_price = price * quantity - discount
    $(this).find('.item-total').text("$"+ parseFloat(total_price).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString())

updateOrderItems()
$(document).on 'keyup', 'tr.order-item input', updateOrderItems
```

Passing the selector to `.on()` will fix your ajax issue.

**To run your code on page load as well as on keyup**

Declare a function, run it on page load, as well as on your `keyup` event.

As an alternative you might want to give your users the possibility to update the information that is displayed, by triggering your code upon a `click` on a button.

Comment: I'd like to have it listen for an .on 'change' event, that way theres no need to listen for a key up. Would the key up work on rows that havent been changed?

Comment: Then maybe replace the comma with a '.' as `parseFloat(2,4)` will not work as you expect it to

Comment: can you think of why this happens? Try readding your `$(document).find(...)`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: 'breaking' is really not helpful ;) Maybe you need to rethink your initial approach. Any peers you could ask for help? I have updated the answer but your code is far from clean

Comment: What is not clean about it? It seems like your solution is pretty clean and it works! I also added a function call to my row when it's being created so it seems to be good all around.

Comment: To mop up that last bit of moisture, get rid of the lambda. `$(document).on 'keyup', 'tr.order-item input', updateOrderItems`